# How can I create Django's form at mongoengine?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-forms, mongoengine

**QUESTION:** Is there decision as similarly as [Django's modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/)?

`pip freeze`:

```
...
pymongo==2.5
mongoengine==0.7.10
...
```

**MY ATTEMPTS:**

[django-mongodbforms](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongodbforms)
It doesn't work. I tried do it but I got an exception which it was fixed by me. Then I got result without form's fields by code:

> ```
> from mongodbforms import DocumentForm
> from myapp.mongomodels import MyModel
>
>
> class BlogForm(DocumentForm):
>     class Meta:
>         document = MyModel
> ```

I didn't continue and decided to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDBForm which you are trying doesn't work with pymongo > 2.2. I think it's not compatible with mongoengine 0.7.x

Comment: Thx, I had understood it. Is there decision similar django-mongodbforms?

Comment: There is not specific group for for django-mongodbforms. But all the decisions happen at [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongoengine-users).